# Removing csrf_token before inserting into MongoDB

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-mongoengine

In my application I use `flask_mongoengine` to connect to a MongoDB. I get the error

> The fields "{'csrf_token'}" do not exist on the document "Study"

when inserting a document.

I manage to overcome the error by manually deleting the csrf_token before saving (see code below). Is there a more elegant way to overcome this error? This would be especially helpful for models containing `EmbeddedDocument` since all the embedded documents have a csrf_token.

**app.py**

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect
from flask_mongoengine.wtf import model_form
from wtforms.meta import DefaultMeta


db = MongoEngine()
bootstrap = Bootstrap()
csrf = CSRFProtect()

app = Flask(__name__)


app.secret_key = 'My secret key'

app.config['MONGODB_HOST'] = 'host'
app.config['MONGODB_PORT'] = 27017
app.config['MONGODB_DB'] = 'database'
app.config['MONGODB_USERNAME'] = 'user'
app.config['MONGODB_PASSWORD'] = 'user'

db.init_app(app)
bootstrap.init_app(app)
csrf.init_app(app)

class Study(db.Document):
    name = db.StringField()

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello_world():

    StudyForm = model_form(Study, field_args={})

    study_form = StudyForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        study_form = StudyForm(request.form)

        if study_form.validate():
            del study_form._fields['csrf_token']
            study_form.save()
            return "Success"

    return render_template('index.html', form=study_form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0')
```

**index.html**

```html
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    <form action="" method="POST">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        {{ form.name.label() }}
        {{ form.name() }}
         <input type=submit class='btn btn-primary '>
    </form>    
</div>    

{% endblock %
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quirk/bug that can be solved as follows.

### Option 1

Pass an instance of your model (`Study`) to the form constructor. You can just pass an empty instance which will get filled with the form values when you save it.

```py
study_form = StudyForm(request.form, instance=Study())
study_form.save()
```

### Option 2

Explicitly create, fill and save the model instance yourself. To fill the form, use [`Form.populate_obj()`](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/forms/#wtforms.form.Form.populate_obj). Note that you must then call `save()` on the model instance, not the form.

```py
study = Study()
study_form.populate_obj(study)
study.save()
```

### Root cause

When Flask-MongoEngine's [`ModelForm.save()`](https://github.com/MongoEngine/flask-mongoengine/blob/8cd926c29b88b8ca0489d99693864be4546f6091/flask_mongoengine/wtf/models.py#L15) needs to create the model instance, it fills it with values from [`Form.data`](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/forms/#wtforms.form.Form.data) which contains *all* form fields, including the `csrf_token`. By contrast, `Form.populate_obj()` discriminates between field types, skipping `CSRFTokenField` instances as desired.

```py
class ModelForm(FlaskForm):
    """A WTForms mongoengine model form"""
    ...

    def save(self, commit=True, **kwargs):
        if self.instance:
            self.populate_obj(self.instance)
        else:
            self.instance = self.model_class(**self.data)

        if commit:
            self.instance.save(**kwargs)
        return self.instance
```